# What's a good way to 0 denominator for ratio calculation?

Tags: programming

I'm writing a program that needs to compute the ratio of the difference between two numbers over the second number.
i.e.,

```
(B-A)/A
```

I'm trying to figure out what's the best way to handle the case of 0 denominator. Practically, I could have a special case for A == 0 and set it to a very small number when that happens. However, how do I pick what number to use? Is there a generally accepted way of handling this?

Comment: No, there's no general way to do this because it depends on what you're trying to do. What does A mean in your application? What do you want to happen when A=0?

Comment: Division by zero is not possible in this case. Output an error message.